# What does the magnification ratio number mean on a macro lens?

Tags: lens, macro, terminology

I'm looking for a macro lens. I have 28-105mm Nikkor which gives me  "1:2 Magnification Ratio" (whatever that means).  I found another lens, Tamron 90mm Macro, which has magnification ratio of 1:1.

Would the Tamron 90mm give me a more close-up shot than my Nikkor? I guess I don't understand what the 1:1 or 1:2 numbers mean.

Comment: related questions that might be useful: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/why-is-11-desirable-for-a-macro-lens http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/what-is-a-macro-lens

Comment: ...Or this one, which is exactly the same question in disguise and (therefore) contains the answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6026

Answer (score 13):

1:2 means the image projected on sensor (or film) is up to half the size of real subject; 1:1 means it's up to exactly the same size as the real subject. So yes, 1:1 means you can take a more close-up shot. The ratio in technical specifications means the maximum magnification, you can magnify less by focusing from further away (or zooming out, if the lens is a zoom).

Approximate minimum size of subject that you can fill a frame with (using minimal focusing distance for the lens, and longest focal length for a zoom lens):

- magnification ratio 1:1 - 24 x 36 mm on full-frame, 16 x 24 mm on APS-C
- magnification ratio 1:2 - 48 x 72 mm on full-frame, 32 x 48 mm on APS-C

You can get even [higher](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/how-can-i-calculate-what-the-effect-of-an-extension-tube-will-be/5629#5629) magnification by adding bellows or extension tube(s) between your camera and lens.

A serious macro shooter may want to consider a Canon system, because they have the [MP-E65](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/lenses/mp-e-65.shtml) lens with insane 5:1 ratio - subject is magnified 5 times compared to its real-life size.

The greater the magnification ratio you use, the thinner will be your depth of field.

As @jrista commented, many people consider only 1:1 or higher magnification lenses to be true macro lenses, while marketers will happily stick "macro" on any lens that will focus closer than lenses of similar focal length usually do.

Comment: It should probably also be noted that "true" macro requires at least 1:1 magnification. A lens with 1:2 magnification can take close-up shots, but they are not truly macro shots, in which the scene is projected life-size onto the sensor.

Comment: @jrista I doubt there is any "official" definition of "macro", but yes, such line is drawn quite often; added a note on that.

Comment: @jrista - I second @Imre on that. A 1:1.1 is just as a macro as 1:1.

Comment: The definition of a macro lens is one that produces a life-size or larger image on the sensor (or film), with a minimum of 1:1 projection. As such, 1:1.1 would NOT qualify, although it would qualify as a close-up lens. The term macroscopic refers to things that can be seen by the naked eye...or "life size" elements of the world, vs. microscopic or smaller than life size. Ref: http://www.bing.com/Dictionary/search?q=define+macro+lens&qpvt=what+is+a+macro+lens%3f&FORM=DTPDIA

Comment: @jrista your ref gives an error page; anyway, I would not consider bing.com, a search engine, ultimate source of truth. Photo.SE answers about [what makes a macro lens](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10569/whats-the-difference-between-a-regular-lens-and-a-macro-lens) indicate that it's enough if the lens focuses close, with 1:1 being a special case. If only 1:1 would be "true macro", we would have to make sure that photos made with 1:1 lens focused even a bit further than minimal focusing distance would NOT be called macro photography, because then they are already less than 1:1.

Comment: Bing just aggregated the result from a dictionary, Encarta I think. The wikipedia article on the subject also calls 1:1 macro lenses "standard" macro lenses, and describes the rest as just close-up photography. The general idea is that you are photographing something at life size. So to provide a looser definition, sure, 1:1.1 or even 1:1.3 is still within the macro range, however 1:2 is HALF life size. I've been involved in a few discussions about this topic online and offline, and to anyone who does a lot of macro work...1:2 is "close-up" photography, where 1:1 or greater is "macro".

Comment: The reason I tend to be a stickler on the point is that to a new buyer who gets into a discussion with an experienced macro photographer an hears that "macro" means "life size", then goes out and buys one of the third-party "macro" lenses that only focus to 1:2, are kind of getting shafted. Nikon and Canon are pretty clear that their macro lenses are full 1:1 magnification, but other manufacturers are sketchy on the point, and they use the term as a marketing ploy rather than as a proper description of the lens. I think new buyers should, ad the very least, be ware.